# nodejs async/await placement for multiple functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

new to programming and I have some questions regarding async,await.
**Models.Callbacks.deleteOne** in the code below is a Mongoose db.. query? Anyways, it is definitely async and returns a Promise.

Q1) Is the below correct? In particular will any errors in **delete_callback** be caught in **do_stuff**?

```
async function delete_callback(msg) {
    await Models.Callbacks.deleteOne({chat_id: msg.chat.id, from_id: msg.from.id});
}

async function do_stuff(msg) {
    try {
        await some_other_async_function(msg);
        delete_callback(msg);
    }
    catch(err) {
        handleError(err);
    }
}
```

Currently, as you can see, there is an **await** inside **delete_callback**, am I allowed to remove that, and instead add another **await** in **do_stuff** when calling **delete_callback(msg)**.

Q2) In other words, if I change it to the code below, will it still work?

```
async function delete_callback(msg) {
    Models.Callbacks.deleteOne({chat_id: msg.chat.id, from_id: msg.from.id});
}

async function do_stuff(msg) {
    try {
        await some_other_async_function(msg);
        await delete_callback(msg);
    }
    catch(err) {
        handleError(err);
    }
}
```

Q3) Furthermore, what happens if **delete_callback** is not an async function in the first place, will any errors from Models.Callbacks.deleteOne be caught??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Q1

No, you can't remove await inside the delete_callback.
And you also need to add await in do_stuff function when calling delete_callback like following code.

The following code will succeed

```
async function delete_callback(msg) {
    await Models.Callbacks.deleteOne({chat_id: msg.chat.id, from_id: msg.from.id});
}

async function do_stuff(msg) {
    try {
        await some_other_async_function(msg);
        // add await here
        await delete_callback(msg);
    }
    catch(err) {
        handleError(err);
    }
}
```

### Q2

You will trigger the function. But you need to add await or return inside the delete_callback.
Otherwise, the delete_callback function will finish immediately.

```
async function delete_callback(msg) {
    return Models.Callbacks.deleteOne({chat_id: msg.chat.id, from_id: msg.from.id});
}

async function do_stuff(msg) {
    try {
        await some_other_async_function(msg);
        await delete_callback(msg);
    }
    catch(err) {
        handleError(err);
    }
}
```

Here is example when you don't add await or return in test() function.
This test function is your delete_callback function.

```
function b() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("doing b");
            resolve();
        }, 5000)
    })
}

async function test () {
    b()
}

async function main() {
    try {
        let a = await test()
        console.log("a: ", a);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log("done");
}

main()
```

### Q3

If delete_callback is not async function, then it's normal function which don't throw error.